# Using Listbox to filter values in DataGridView()

Tags: c#, datagridview, listbox

I have created a listbox that displays all values that I want to use as a filter for my datagridview.

So this is the listbox I want the selected value from this to be used as a controler/parameter to filter the values shown in

Answer (score 1):

You would need to enumerate over each item within your control.  For the `ListBox` the code would be:

```
foreach(var item in example.Items)
{
     // This will expose the internal data, via item now.
}
```

However, I believe the exact functionality you want, would be:

```
var item = example.SelectedItem;
```

This would provide you with the selected information.  You may require to anchor to the `ListBox` event: `SelectedIndexChanged`.  This way you could pass a numeric representation to a global to utilize or another approach.

Comment: Not sure exactly how you mean, my filter button will have to update my DataGridView. But the variable will have to store the value selected in the listview that can later be used in the conditional logic of the SQL query for the datagridView {  "Select fname,ename FROM dbo.Users u inner join dbo.Company c on c.companyName = u.company where company ="+selectedItem" @Greg

Comment: @SterlinkArcher If you concat in that manner, you would allow SQL injection.  Since the value from the listbox, would be how it is passed.  Which means, should another value enter, you may be able to inject.  I would recommend parameterize the query.

Comment: yes parameterized query is the best option, I have updated my original post accordingly. I want to parameterize a value from the listbox and use it in my conditional logic in the DataGridView

Answer (score 1):

After a conversation with the asker, the final solution is below. Needed to handle the listbox's SelectedIndexChanged event and within that event give the DataGridView a filter.

```
public partial class CompanyForm : Form
{
    private DataTable dataEmployeesSource = new DataTable();

    public CompanyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        initDataEmployees();
        initCompanyList();

        companyList.SelectedIndexChanged += listbox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    private void initDataEmployees()
    {
        const string sql = "Select fname, ename, c.companyName AS companyName FROM dbo.Users u inner join dbo.Company c on c.companyName = u.company;";
        dataEmployeesSource = selectIntoDataTable(sql);
        dataEmployees.DataSource = dataEmployeesSource;
    }

    private void initCompanyList()
    {
        const string sql = "Select companyName from dbo.Company";
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = selectIntoDataTable(sql);
            companyList.DataSource = dt;
            companyList.ValueMember = "companyName";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no companies to display");
        }
    }

    private DataTable selectIntoDataTable(string sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    a.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
            return dt;
        }

    private void listbox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView selectedRow = (DataRowView)companyList.SelectedItem;
        string selectedText = (string)selectedRow.Row["companyName"];
        DataView dv = dataEmployeesSource.DefaultView;

        string columnName = dataEmployeesSource.Columns[2].ColumnName;
        string filter = string.Format("{0} = '{1}'", columnName, selectedText);
        dv.RowFilter = filter;
        dataEmployees.DataSource = dv;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer :) Hmm I could get rid off it but I still need it to control the data in my DataGridView, the purpose of this is to use the ListBox values to filter other information in my DataGridView each company has employees so if I select Company1 then I want the Company1 employees listed in my DataGridView if you understand how I mean

Comment: @SterlinkArcher was my answer able to help with your question, is there anything else you need help with or cleared up?

Comment: I understand your answer, but I want to know how to parameterize the selectedValue from the listbox and use it in my conditional logic at my DataGridView. You can see my updated code and question

Comment: @SterlinkArcher I've updated my answer to show filtering of the DataGridView. Let me know if you have any problems applying what I've demonstrated to your own code.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I understand your concept. But 0 of my own code is incorporated in it and there's no consideration of the use of SQL, Connection string that is being used to fill the listbox and the datagridView. Which makes it hard for me to implement the code.

Comment: I was avoiding using your code because I couldn't use your connection string and such, but I'll have type it all out for you since you're having a hard time implementing it. Can't guarantee it is bug free since I can't test it completely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132853/discussion-between-sterlinkarcher-and-blake-thingstad).